# How to get regression to optimise coefficients and data array? Python

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, regression

Edited: 31/7/19

I have a data set which has PGR (pasture growth rate) and Foo (amount of pasture) readings for 4 sites for about 6 weeks of the year. The relationship between PGR and Foo is inverse exponential.

What I would like to do is group the weeks into 3 lots. Weeks with a similar relationship between PGR and Foo would be together.

Group size doesn't have to be the same.
But weeks must be consecutive, ie
Group one - week 1 , week 2, week 3.
Group two - week 4.
Group three - week 5, week 6.

What I would like to do is create 3 regressions that optimise to reduce the sum of squares and at the same time optimise the week selection.

The example above would suggest that weeks 1 - 3 are similar, 4 is different to 3, and 5 & 6 are similar to each other but different to 4. (I want this grouping to happen automatically based on the regressions)

The code below is my attempt however it doesn't work (I have included it to help better explain what I am trying to do).

```
data = {'Week':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6],
'PGR':[10,29,34.93,32,10,29,34.93,35,31,36,34.93,37,40,46,50,52,40,60,65,68,42,62,65,68],
'Foo': [20,45,102.28,66.79,25,50,90,75,50,75,90,130,50,75,90,130,30,60,105,150,35,60,110,140]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def group(x):
    a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j, w, z, y = x

    #below defines the groups, I want z, y & w to be optimised when this function is solverd
    #This determines which weeks are in which groups
    group1 = df.loc[(df['Week'] == range(1,z))]
    group2 = df.loc[(df['Week'] == range(z,y))]
    group3 = df.loc[(df['Week'] == range(y,w))]

    #Once the groups are defined this will extract Foo and PGR values for regressions
    xm1 = group1['Foo'].to_numpy()
    ym1 = group1['PGR'].to_numpy()

    xm2 = group2['Foo'].to_numpy()
    ym2 = group2['PGR'].to_numpy()

    xm3 = group3['Foo'].to_numpy()
    ym3 = group3['PGR'].to_numpy()

    #These are the 3 regressions
    y1 = a + b / xm1 + c * np.log(xm1)
    SSE1 = (y1 - ym1)**2
    y2 = e + f / xm2 + g * np.log(xm2)
    SSE2 = (y2 - ym2) ** 2
    y3 = h + i / xm3 + j * np.log(xm3)
    SSE3 = (y3 - ym3) ** 2
    return SSE1, SSE2, SSE3

#I now have the sum of squares for all the regressions, which I want to minimise
#Minimising can happen by selecting groups that are more similar or by changing the regression coefficients 
def objective(x):
    return np.sum(group(x))

x0 = np.zeros(12)

# bounds for a, b, c,  e, f, g, h, i, j, w, z, y
bndspositive = (0,52)
bnds100 = (-100.0, 100.0)
no_bnds = (-1.0e10, 1.0e10)
bnds = (no_bnds, no_bnds, bnds100, no_bnds, no_bnds, bnds100, no_bnds, no_bnds, bnds100, bndspositive, bndspositive, bndspositive)

# optimise groups and regressions for best fit
solution = minimize(objective, x0, method=None, bounds=bnds)

# solution
x = solution.x
```

Hopefully this makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to fit the data as a 3D surface. My equation search turned up "Foo = a * PGR + b * week^2 + Offset" as a likely candidate equation, with parameters a = 2.90940013, b = -2.33138779, and Offset = -10.04234205 yielding RMSE = 22.02 and R-squared = 0.6338. Here is a graphical Python fitter with your data and this equation.

[image: scatterplot]

[image: surfaceplot]

[image: contourplot]

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('Week') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('PGR') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Foo') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('Week') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('PGR') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('Week')
    axes.set_ylabel('PGR')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Foo')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, b, Offset):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    return a*y + b*numpy.square(x) + Offset


if __name__ == "__main__":

    week = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6]
    PGR = [10,29,34.93,32,10,29,34.93,35,31,36,34.93,37,40,46,50,52,40,60,65,68,42,62,65,68]
    Foo = [20,45,102.28,66.79,25,50,90,75,50,75,90,130,50,75,90,130,30,60,105,150,35,60,110,140]

    xData = numpy.array(week, dtype=numpy.float32)
    yData = numpy.array(PGR, dtype=numpy.float32)
    zData = numpy.array(Foo, dtype=numpy.float32)

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Comment: Hi James, That is a good way to visually group the weeks however I'm trying to avoid having to do it visually. That method also only applies one function to all weeks, where as I want to group the weeks into three lots and then apply a customised function to each (ie one function per group)

Comment: On the basis of the regression analysis I presented, it does not appear to me that there are three groups of data. What would be the basis for grouping the data into three categories?

Comment: That is only a simplified data set, maybe i should edit that to make more of a difference between the weeks.
My real problem is looking at pasture growth throughout a year, in this case the relationship between growth (PGR) and amount of pasture (FOO) changes throughout the year ie in winter growth is minimal even at high levels of FOO. However, in spring pasture grows at a much greater rate. Because of this i want more than one regression to represent my data.

Comment: That is an excellent answer to my question, thank you for the detailed reply.